# EF Core 2.2 - How to preserve context with scaffolding

Tags: ef-core-2.2

New to EF Core so apologies if this comes off as a little general.  I'm working on an app where we are using database first and scaffolding to our API layer.  As I understand it, the context gets regenerated every time we run the scaffolding to bring in new database objects.  The problem is that I need, I think, to make a change in how I'm trying to filter active results.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>(entity =>
{
    // here's the problem
    entity.HasQueryFilter(d => d.IsActive);

    entity.HasOne(d => d.Invoice)
       .WithMany(p => p.Order)
       .HasForeignKey(d => d.InvoiceId)
       .HasConstraintName("FK_Order_Invoice");
```

I'm  trying to add the .HasQueryFilter so that only Orders that have been marked as active are returned.  The problem is that since we're using scaffolding, this would get overwritten every time I generate a new context.  Is there any way I can preserve that?

Comment: With scaffolding - no. With some [external tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/) like [EF Core Power Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/#ef-core-power-tools) reverse engineering - yes.

Comment: Yeah, we're restricted from using most third party stuff unfortunately

Comment: @TrevorGoodchild EF Core Power Tools is a Visual Studio 2017 extension.